# Why is my git branch not pointing to the latest commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm seeing the following graph in SourceTree. I have the 'dev' branch checked out, and I don't understand why I'm pointing to the commit that's highlighted in blue, instead of the commit at the top of the list.

[image]

The graph suggests that the commit at the top of the list has been commited on the dev branch (although I always find the SourceTree graph confusing, I'm not sure if this is actually what the graph is telling me). If I do:

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard head
```

then I'm still on the same commit that's highlighted in blue. Also I'm unclear on why the master branch is showing a marker of 'origin/HEAD'. Shouldn't the commit at the top of the list be marked 'origin/HEAD'. What's going on here, and is there something I need to do to fix this?

Comment: `git reset --hard head` This command doesn't make any sense. Do you mean `git reset --hard HEAD`?

Comment: When I run `git reset --hard head` in one of my repos, I get an error: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The graph suggests that the commit at the top of the list has been commited on the dev branch

This is an incorrect reading of the graph. The `dev` branch contains the commit with the message "Merged in FD-50-Reboot-scheduler" and the connected ones below it. It does not contain any of the commits above.

The top commit is on a branch named `origin/Demo-fake-data`.

> Also I'm unclear on why the master branch is showing a marker of 'origin/HEAD'. Shouldn't the commit at the top of the list be marked 'origin/HEAD'. What's going on here, and is there something I need to do to fix this?

`HEAD` is a special name for the currently checked out commit. `origin/HEAD` is the commit that is checked out on the remote named `origin`. There is nothing to fix here. If you are working on a team, you shouldn't mess with the remote repo at all unless you have been assigned that responsibility.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice. One last question - for the commits at the top of the chart that aren't showing a branch - what branch have they been committed on, if not the dev branch?

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow A branch points at single commit, called the "head" of the branch. Each commit will point at one or more parent commits (except for the first commit in the repo). A branch contains its head commit and all of the commits that can be traced through those parent connections.

Comment: For example, all of the blue dots are commits on the branch named `origin/Demo-fake-data`. But the pink dots are not on that branch. They are on a branch named `origin/FD-54-Boarding-pass-demo`.

Answer (score 6):

This is all a sidebar, but it matters a lot sometimes.  Sometimes, it matters less or not at all, but it's worth knowing:

- `HEAD`, in all uppercase, has a special meaning to Git. This can also be spelled `@`.
- `head`, in lowercase, does not have the special meaning.

If you're on a case-insensitive file system (e.g., Windows and MacOS default), the all-lowercase name head winds up matching the file that Git stores the `@` data in, which—for the main work-tree anyway—is named `.git/HEAD`.  So it winds up sort-of-working, on Windows and MacOS.  It does not work on Linux by default, and it does not work correctly in added work-trees.<sup>1</sup>  Always use the `@` or `HEAD` spelling to make sure it works for you in all cases.

> Also I'm unclear on why the master branch is showing a marker of 'origin/HEAD'. Shouldn't the commit at the top of the list be marked 'origin/HEAD'. What's going on here ...?

To build a bit on what [Code-Apprentice said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985800/1256452): your own Git copies, into your own Git repository, the branch names it sees on the other Git over at `origin`.  It prefixes these copied names with `origin/` so that you can tell them apart from *your* names.  That's why you end up with an `origin/master`, `origin/dev`, and so on: their Git has a `master`, a `dev`, and so on.

Just like your own repository, which has the special name `HEAD` to remember which *branch name* you have checked out, their Git has a current branch name.  At some point early on, you ran `git clone url` (or some GUI equivalent of this command) to *create* your Git repository.  Your Git called up their Git and got not only their list of branch names, but also the contents of their `@` / `HEAD` current-branch information.  That—which in this case is `master`—selected which *branch* your Git created in your new clone, based on the `origin/master` your Git created based on their `master`.  (Whew!)

After your Git went through all of this process of reading their `HEAD` (and seeing `master`) so as to read their `master` (your `origin/master`) so as to create your `master`, your Git created a *symbolic reference* in your own repository to remind you that their `HEAD` contained their name `master` which you're calling `origin/master`.  That reminder stays around in your repository pretty much forever.  It's not very useful.  In fact, it seems to be completely useless—I've never found any use for it myself.  But it's there!

---

<sup>1</sup>On those systems where it sort-of-works, what happens is that `head`, in lowercase, matches the `.git/HEAD` (uppercase) file, so you get the commit being used in / by the *main* work-tree, instead of the commit being used in / by the current added work-tree.

Comment: To add to this, assuming the user is on a system where `git reset --hard head` works, then the user just reset the working tree and index to `HEAD`. Since `HEAD` is the current commit, this does nothing if the user hasn't made any changes to the tracked files.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is only showing that is older commit in other branches that are not merged with the current one. For me is less confusion check the selector `current branch` in sourcetree.

When you reset the branch, you probably don't have the last version of `origin/dev`, either the other braches you are seeing discordances.

Try:

```
git stash # if needed
git checkout dev
git fetch origin dev
git reset --hard origin/dev # or git reset --hard HEAD  
git stash pop # if needed
```

Here is where `current branch` selector is. This doesn't change anything, just visualization:

[image]

Notice: you can use `git fetch --all` but I usually don't, I don't need everything update just the branches I am working on.

Comment: Thanks @Raul Martin, this kind of makes sense, however I don't understand what you mean by 'the graph is only showing that is older commit in other branches that are not merged with the current one". I've changed the image to show the dates of the commits. The commits that are above the one I'm pointing are are *newer*. And if I follow your instructions to fetch and reset for the branch, I'm still pointing to the same commit (13th August). And why is origin/HEAD showing on the master branch and not my dev branch?

Comment: Doing a hard reset here dangerous and probably not warranted. If anything, the OP should use `git merge` or use whatever Pull Request system is in place to merge into `dev`.

Comment: When I run `git reset --hard head` in one of my repos, I get an error: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`.

Comment: +1 for the hint to show 'current branch', however @Code-Apprentice has correctly identified what should be done, and that a hard reset is incorrect

Comment: Changing head By HEAD as recommended in other answers.
Aside from that.  `hard reset` is not incorrect. I used it as a part of my workflow in the branches I should not develop on like a master. Or branches that are my source for a feature that I am not maintaining. Just you have to be aware that is not `working-directory` safe.